# How to fix Mac's swiss keyboard to do braces correctly?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm a swiss developer and always developed under Windows or Linux. On those platforms, the swiss keyboard layout did the following:

```
Alt Gr + ä: {
Alt Gr + $: }
Alt Gr + ü: [
Alt Gr + ¨: ]
```

But on the mac and with swiss keyboard layout selected i get the following:

```
Alt Gr + ä: æ
Alt Gr + $: ¶
Alt Gr + ü: §
Alt Gr + ¨: ‘
```

and instead

```
Alt Gr + 8: {
Alt Gr + 9: }
Alt Gr + 5: [
Alt Gr + 6: ]
```

which is absolutely annoying :(

Is there a way to fix mac's swiss layout to behave correctly? It actually looks like a bug to me...

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found the solution:
http://www.krenger.ch/blog/mac-os-x-standard-de_ch-keymap/

Sadly, I can't upload the keyboard layout file to superuser.com :(